# Start Kinesis consumer only when there's over x number of records?

Tags: amazon-kinesis

Is there a way to create a Kinesis consumer with buffer limits? Like [here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-connectors/blob/13e41407e617aadf248ca7e636af2f198bdfae4e/samples/src/main/resources/S3Sample.properties#L9):

```
#Flush when buffer exceeds 100000 Amazon Kinesis records, 64 MB size limit or when time since last buffer exceeds 1 hour
bufferByteSizeLimit = 67108864 
bufferRecordCountLimit = 100000
bufferMillisecondsLimit = 3600000
```

Essentially, I want to start `IRecordProcessor` only when there's a significant amount of data. I can't use the connector code above because I need the [latest](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/amazon-kinesis-client/1.9.3) version of `amazon-kinesis-client`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing my own solution.

1. Have a `ConcurrentHashMap` to store the streaming data

   ```
     private val recsMap = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, List[RecordStore]]
     private val currByteSize = new AtomicLong(0L)
     private val currRecordCount = new AtomicLong(0L)
     private val currSeconds = new AtomicLong(0L)
   ```
2. Update the counters (by size/time/# of records)
3. Flush data out when counters' reached

   ```
     recsMap.foreach(write2File())
     // clean up
     recsMap.remove(writtenRecs())
   ```
4. checkpointing and reset counters

   ```
     // reset counters
     currByteSize.getAndSet(value)
     currRecordCount.getAndSet(value)
     currSeconds.getAndSet(value)
   ```